# jquery - change a drop down menu to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to convert a drop down menu to be a list using jquery... so:

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

to

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just iterate over the `<option>` elements and create a corresponding `<li>` for each, then add them to a `<ul>`, like this: (where `#menu` is the ID of your drop-down)

```
var list = $('<ul>');
$('#menu option').each(function() {
  $('<li>').text($(this).text()).appendTo(list);
});
list.appendTo($('body'));
```

[Working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/onaxi4)

Comment: nice work-around. You can use `$('#menu').replaceWith(list);` in this case if you wish to swap it in. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/onaxi4/3)

Answer (score 2):

Initially wrap select in span as shown below -

Try this -

```
  <span id="replace">
    <select id="test">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </span>

var html = '<ul>';
$('#test option').each(function(){
html += '<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>';
});
html += '</ul>';

$('#replace').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Magic!!!

If you get the data by any means

replace the dropdown by .html() or .text().

populate the ul and li  and concatinate into a variable like

```
var newcontent = "<ul> 
<li>1</li> 
<li>2</li> 
<li>3</li> 
</ul> "
```

i assume the select box is in a div with id "content"

replace content by `('#content').html(newcontent )`

or text.

NB. You should get the data and create the ul li . then you can replace

Answer (score 0):

Tag names are immutable in DOM elements. If possible you should consider including both in the source code and then use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to switch